# How can I pass parameters to an helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I want to pass some parameters from my HTML to my meteor helper.

Can I do something like this? ->

```
{{myHelper "customText"}}
```

or

```
{{myHelper context="customText"}}
```

If so, how do I get back the string "customText"? Is it something like this? ->

```
"myHelper": function(context){
    return this.dataset[context]?"success":"danger"
},
```

thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly like the 1st option, accessing as you said.

Comment: damn, I only tried the second option, convinced it would not be that straightforward. Please add an answer, I'll validate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parameters to a help like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
...
{{myHelper param}}
...
</template>
```

Then access it in your .js file:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
   myHelper: function(param) {
      // do anything with param
   }
});
```